# Weighted Loss in Huggingface Generator module

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface, huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface-trainer

I am using Huggginface's Seq2SeqTrainer module and Generator modules for my encoder-decoder models. I have to use weighted sample loss calculation in each mini-batches. Does anyone know how to achieve this ?
Is there a way to do weighted loss in each example for each token losses as well ?